# Comparing multiple rows of data within a date range to create a new table in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm a novice to SQL & MS-Access, however I have a table of data in MS-Access that looks like:

```
ID | Start_Time | End_Time 
1  | 1:00:00 PM | 1:00:30 PM
2  | 2:15:10 PM | 2:15:50 PM
3  | 2:15:30 PM | 2:18:40 PM
4  | 2:17:00 PM | 2:17:30 PM
5  | 2:45:10 PM | 3:03:10 PM
```

Each row is sequentially recorded into the database. I want to compare the start and end times of each and combine together rows that overlap. For instance, ID 1's `Start_Time` and `End_Time` do not overlap any other times in the table, therefore, it would get posted into the new table. However, ID 2 through 4 have `Start_Time`s and `End_Time`s that overlap with ID 2's `Start_Time` as `Start_Time` of the group and ID 3's `End_Time` as the `End_Time` of the group ID 2 through 4.

The end result would be a new table that should look like:

```
ID | Start_Time | End_Time   | Duration_seconds
1  | 1:00:00 PM | 1:00:30 PM | 30
2  | 2:15:10 PM | 2:18:40 PM | 210
3  | 2:45:10 PM | 3:03:10 PM | 1080
```

How can I do this in SQL/MS-Access?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This might need a few passes through the recordsets.

Define 2 new variables.   NewStart and NewEnd.  As you grab each ID,  assign the existing start/end times.
Using a nested loop compare each record to every other record (new times).   If the start time is between the time range then replace that IDs NewStart as the other IDs start time.  The NewEnd will be assigned the greater of the current ID or comparitive IDs end time.

As you cycle through,  items 3 and 4 will have the same  "new" times as ID 2.  All will have transformed "new" times.

After this, you query distinct times for each ID